# How to swap image on mouseover and back to the original one on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Hi everyone im new to the community and hope to find some help!
Im at beginner level at javascript! been trying to have this done but can't seem to find anything online hope someone can help me out!

```
 <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {

        var sImg1 = document.getElementById("img1").src = "images/image_1P.jpg";

        // mouseover
        sImg1.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
                sImg1.getElementById("myImg1").src = "images/image_1C.jpg";
            })
            //mouseout
        sImg1.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            sImg1.getElementById("myImg1").src = "images/image_1P.jpg";
        })
    })
</script>



<body>
<img class="img1" id="myImg1" src="" width="150" height="200">
```

Id like for the image to swap from 1p to 1c on mouseover and from 1c to 1p on mouseout !

Answer (score 1):

What your script does and doesn't.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    var sImg1 = document.getElementById("img1").src = "images/image_1P.jpg";
    //sImg1 is a string which doesn't have events

    // mouseover makes no sense (see above)
    sImg1.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            sImg1.getElementById("myImg1").src = "images/image_1C.jpg";
        })
        //mouseout
    sImg1.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        sImg1.getElementById("myImg1").src = "images/image_1P.jpg";
    })
})
```

How to fix.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    var sImg1 = document.getElementById("myImg1");
    sImg1.src = "images/image_1P.jpg";

    // mouseover
    sImg1.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            //this is an event source
            this.src = "images/image_1C.jpg";
        });
        //mouseout
    sImg1.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        this.src = "images/image_1P.jpg";
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no id with `img1`. It should be `myImg1`. So your `var sImg1 = document.getElementById("img1")` is `null`.

There are many other problems with your code. In line `var sImg1 = document.getElementById("img1").src = "images/image_1P.jpg";`. You are not selecting the element, instead you are doing assignment operation. So, your `sImg1` will have `image path`. It is similar like doing `const a = b = 10;`

After you add event listeners, you have `sImg1.getElementById("myImg1")`, which is incorrect. It should be `document.getElementById("myImg1")`.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    const sImg1 = document.getElementById("myImg1");

    sImg1.src= "images/image_1P.jpg"
    sImg1.alt = "image_1P.jpg";

    sImg1.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        sImg1.src = "images/image_1C.jpg";
        sImg1.alt = "image_1C.jpg";
    });

    sImg1.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        sImg1.src = "images/image_1P.jpg";
        sImg1.alt = "image_1P.jpg";
    });
});
```

```html
<img class="img1" id="myImg1" src="" width="150" height="200">
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! this really help me out !

Comment: @FabioBrizzi - If the answer solves your problem, mark it as accepted so as to indicate that problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is absolutely right， but you made some programming mistakes.
I don't think it is a good idea to use `continuous assignment` in Javascript, which is considered a bad practice in many languages.

```
var sImg1 = document.getElementById("img1").src = "images/image_1P.jpg";
```

In the above line, `sImg1` is `"images/image_1P.jpg"`, not dom.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {

        var sImg1 = document.getElementById("img1")
        sImg1.src = "images/image_1P.jpg";

        // mouseover
        sImg1.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
                // you have sImg1 already
                sImg1.src = "images/image_1C.jpg";
            })
            //mouseout
        sImg1.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            sImg1.src = "images/image_1P.jpg";
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: This is comment, not answer. Please edit or delete.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev markit on mobile. You guys are really quick.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .card {
        width: 130px;
        height: 195px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 50px;
    }
    .card .img-top {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }
    .card:hover .img-top {
        display: inline;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card">
    <img src="/examples/images/card-back.jpg" alt="Card Back">

    <img src="/examples/images/card-front.jpg" class="img-top" alt="Card Front">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: just try code . on hover mouse card-front.jpg image came . here card-back.jpg is replaced with card-front.jpg image on hover (see css in style)

Comment: Okay. But the OP had asked for JS solution.